# Inversify-Express-Utils Decorator @requestBody not working

Tags: node.js, express, dto, inversifyjs, inversify-express-utils

Trying to validate the request through the DTO by calling the @requestBody annotation at the controller route.

Controller Method -

```
@httpPost('/login')
    public async login(@request() req: Request, @response() res: Response, @requestBody() body: LoginDto): Promise<any> {
        console.log(" ~ file: auth.controller.ts:20 ~ AuthController ~ login ~ body:", body)
        return res.status(200).json(body);
    }
```

DTO -

```
export interface LoginDto {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Request Body -

```
{
  email: 'helloworld@email.com',
  password: '1234',
  confirm_password: '1234'
}
```

Expected Output -

```
~ file: auth.controller.ts:20 ~ AuthController ~ login ~ body: {
      email: 'helloworld@email.com',
      password: '1234'
    }
```

Actual Output -

```
~ file: auth.controller.ts:20 ~ AuthController ~ login ~ body: {
  email: 'helloworld@email.com',
  password: '1234',
  confirm_password: '1234'
}
```

The DTO is not working as expected.Not sure whats going on wrong.If anyone has experienced this before and have a solution for it, then it would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: What result did you expect? What do you mean by "it's not working"

Comment: the interface of the dto doesn't have confirm_password field, so it shouldn't technically output that when I try to print the body. I hope that makes sense. I will just edit the question to include the expected output.

Comment: I don't think the `inversify-express-utils` package will modify the request body at runtime to satisfy the TS interface. See this test https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils/blob/v6.4.3/test/fetures/controller_inheritance.test.ts#L136

Comment: oh thanks for the heads up! Is there any other way that I can achieve this perhaps any other package

Answer (score 0):

if you used `inversify-express-utils` first you need to parse body in the starting point of your application

```
var container = new Container();
const server = new InversifyExpressServer(container);
server.setConfig((app) => {
   app.use(express.json());
});
```

then you can try to listen your server with this way:

```
const app = server.build()
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 3000`);
});
```

dont forget to import the `express`